# LARAVEL: Verificando se há retorno em SQL

Tags: sql, laravel, condição

estou precisando de uma ajuda!

Tenho uma consulta SQL em Laravel da seguinte forma:

```
$cliente = DB::table('clientes')->where(DB::raw("cpf = '$cpf' AND (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(telefone1_num, '(', ''), ')',''), '-',''),' ','') LIKE '%$telefone%' OR REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(telefone2_num, '(', ''), ')',''), '-',''),' ','') LIKE '%$telefone%' OR REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(telefone3_num, '(', ''), ')',''), '-',''),' ','') LIKE '%$telefone%')"))->first();
```

Simplesmente preciso verificar se ela me retornou resultados.
Já tentei da seguinte forma:

```
if (is_null($cliente) || $cliente == null ) {
   return $this->sendError(config('global.cliente_nao_encontrado'));
}
```

Mas mesmo assim entra no `if`. Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Tem certeza que a SQL retorna resultados?

Comment: Sim amigo! Testei aqui já! Nela eu só removo a máscara normalmente e comparo!

Comment: Já tentou um dd($cliente); ?

Comment: a comparação `is_null($cliente)` e `$cliente == null` são a mesma coisa;
tente usar o método `exists()`; `$client->exists()`

Comment: @RFL não são a mesma coisa. Uma verifica **se é** nulo, a outra **se é igual** a nulo. Parece a mesma coisa, mas como é usada a comparação frouxa, o valor `false`, por exemplo, não satisfaz a primeira, mas satisfaz a segunda.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss é verdade, eu havia esquecido do `==`, acadei escrevendo `==` pensando em `===`

Comment: Pessoal, consegui solucionar, a consulta em laravel escrita dessa forma por algum motivo inclui um `is null` no final da SQL. Resumindo, não existia retorno, fiz de outra forma e com essa verificação mesmo funcionou!

Answer (score -2):

```
if($cliente->isNotEmpty()) {}
```

Ou somente assim

```
if($client){}
```

Comment: Poderia explicar o que esse código faz, onde o colega deve colocar ele, etc... Não é interessante sair jogando códigos e não explicar sua função...